# Android RecyclerView in ScrollView in SwipeRefresh is not visible

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I have `RecyclerView` inside `ScrollView` which is inside `SwipeRefresh` layout. I have few layouts on top of `RecyclerView`, but my `RecyclerView` is not visible, even if i remove other layouts from `ScrollView`. What do you suggest? I need to put list below some layouts in `ScrollView` somehow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">    
                ....
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/simpleList"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </ScrollView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Tried to give specific height but still not visible o.O

If i **replace** `RecyclerView` with `ListView`, then list is visible.

Comment: Try giving the RecyclerView some static height value, also please add screenshot to your question

Comment: @jacktech24 I will change its height depending on list item count

Comment: @jacktech24 there is just toolbar, nothing else. So no need to add screenshot

Comment: Then you don't want RecyclerView but rather an LinearLayout and manually adding items to it, because from what you say, you want to have all the items visible right?

Comment: yes but that way it is not efficient.

Comment: Can you remove the scrollView and see how that goes.

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov that's not true, if you want to have all the items visible, then RecyclerView makes no sense

Comment: @Diyoda i tried removing scrollview which doesnt work. Also tried removing swiperefresh, again no luck)

Comment: @Diyoda only way it works just recyclerview inside linear layout

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov are you setting the recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

Comment: @Diyoda of course, but it should be visible on xml first

Comment: Can you put elements that you want to keep above recyclerview in the first cell of recyclerview and put recyclerview inside linearlayout instead of scrollview?

Comment: You must set fillViewport="true" on scrollview, and if you have issue with scrolling, this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37619660/1303639

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to put `android:fillViewport="true"` to `SwipeRefreshLayout`. And now `RecyclerView` is visible.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have all the items of the list always visible then replace RecyclerView with LinearLayout and add your items to it.

### An example:

**your_layout.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">    
                    ....
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/simpleList"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"/>

            </ScrollView>
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_text"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**And in your Java code:**

first declare the list

```
mSimpleList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.simpleList);
```

then method for adding the items

```
public void addListItems(ArrayList<String> strings) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    for(String s : strings) {
        View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, mSimpleList, false);
        TextView text = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
        text.setText(s);
        mSimpleList.addView(item);//you can add layout params if you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My earlier answer is blocking the down scroll. So, a good work around will be add your Stuff as the first element of the `RecyclerView`. That can be easily implemented using the adapter. That way you can still scroll your stuff as well as your actual list elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/simpleList"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/your_stuff" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And using something like the following for your adapter implimentation,

```
  public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    class YourStuffViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //
    }

    class ViewHolderListItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

          if(position>0){
               return 1;
          }
          return 0;

    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         switch (viewType) {
             case 0: return new YourStuffViewHolder();
             case 1: return new ViewHolderListItem ();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the layout above list does not fit to screen, i can not scroll then

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov you want that to be scrolled as well (Your stuff on top of the RecyclerView). What do you mean by Does not fit to screen. That LinearLayout is not scrollable. Only the recyclerview.

Comment: The general advice is not to put scrollable element inside another scrollable element in this case RecyclerView inside ScrollView